# ASP.net MVC Kendo UI Grid column headers not aligning to table cells

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Hey all I'm new to Kendo and I'm trying to fix my grid data in its spot and not move when I resize the browsers window. Currently when resizing it lower it starts cutting off the column names and the data below them. This is not the results I want.

I want to be able to resize it and the "table" grid stay the same size no matter what.

My .cshtml page code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ToolBar().....

@(Html.Kendo().Grid < Demo.Tool.Web.Core.Entities.BatchItem > ()
    .Name("batches")
    .Columns(c => {
        c.AutoGenerate(false);
        c.Bound(b => b.Id).Visible(false).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new {
            style = "text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; table-layout: fixed;"
        });
        c.Bound(b => b.Description).Width("200").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new {
            style = "text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; table-layout: fixed;"
        });
        c.Bound(b => b.PercentageComplete).Width("200").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new {
                style = "text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; table-layout: fixed;"
            })
            /*Percentage Complete*/
            .HtmlAttributes(new {
                style = "text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; table-layout: fixed;"
            })
            .ClientTemplate("<div class='not-progress'>" +
                "<div class='batch-not-progress'></div>" +
                "<span>0%</span>" +
                "</div>" +
                "<div class='progress batch-progress'></div>")
            .Width("200");
        c.Bound(b => b.SubmissionTime).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss}")
            /*Submission Time*/
            .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new {
                style = "text-align: center;"
            })
            .HtmlAttributes(new {
                style = "text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; table-layout: fixed;"
            })
            .Width("200");
        c.Bound(b => b.Status).ClientTemplate("#= BatchMonitor.getStatusTemplate(Status) #")
            /*Status*/
            .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new {
                style = "text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; table-layout: fixed;"
            })
            .Width("200");
        c.Bound(b => b.Rank).Title("Priority").ClientTemplate("<span/>")
            /*Priority*/
            .HtmlAttributes(new {
                style = "text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; table-layout: fixed;"
            })
            .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new {
                style = "text-align: center;", @class = "batch-monitor-grid-batches-header"
            })
            .Filterable(false)
            .Sortable(false)
            .Width("200");
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new {
        @class = "batch-monitor-grid batch-monitor-detail-grid batch-monitor-grid-batches"
    })
    .ClientDetailTemplateId("grdBatchMonitorJobTemplate")
    .AutoBind(false)
    .DataSource(ds => {
        ds.WebApi()
            .ServerOperation(true)
            .Model(m => {
                m.Id(b => b.Id);
            })
            .Read(r => r.Url(string.Format("{0}://{1}/api/v1/jobbatch", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host)).Type(HttpVerbs.Get)).PageSize(10);
    })
    .Events(e => e.DataBound("BatchMonitor.onDatabound")
        .DetailExpand("BatchMonitor.onDetailViewExpand")
        .DetailCollapse("BatchMonitor.onDetailViewCollapse")
        .Change("BatchMonitor.onBatchGridChange"))
    .Pageable(p => p.Refresh(true)
        .PageSizes(new int[] {
            5,
            10,
            25,
            50,
            100
        })
        .Numeric(true))
    .Scrollable(s => s.Virtual(GridVirtualizationMode.Columns).Height("auto"))
    .Resizable(r => r.Columns(true))
    .Sortable(s => s.SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn))
    .Selectable(s => s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
    .ColumnMenu(c => c.Columns(false))
    .Filterable()) 
<script type = "text/kendo-tmpl" id = "grdBatchMonitorJobTemplate">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid < Demo.Tool.Web.Core.Entities.JobItem > ()
    .Name("grdJobs_#=Id#")
    .HtmlAttributes(new {
        @class = "batch-monitor-grid batch-monitor-detail-grid batch-monitor-grid-no-alt-row-color"
    })
    .Columns(c => {
        c.AutoGenerate(false);
        c.Bound(j => j.Description).Width("200").HtmlAttributes(new {
            style = "text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; table-layout: fixed;"
        });
        c.Bound(j => j.PercentageComplete).ClientTemplate("<div><div class='not-progress'><div class='job-not-progress'></div><span>0%</span></div><div class='progress job-progress'></div></div>")
            .Width("200")
            .HtmlAttributes(new {
                style = "text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; table-layout: fixed;"
            });
        c.Bound(j => j.Id).Width("200").ClientTemplate("<span></span>");
        c.Bound(j => j.Status).Width("200").ClientTemplate("\\#= BatchMonitor.getStatusTemplate(Status)\\#").HtmlAttributes(new {
            style = "text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; table-layout: fixed;"
        });
        c.Bound(j => j.Rank).Width("200").HtmlAttributes(new {
            style = "text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; table-layout: fixed;"
        });
    })
    .Events(e => e.DataBound("BatchMonitor.onJobGridDatabound")
        .Change("BatchMonitor.onJobGridChange")
        .DetailCollapse("BatchMonitor.onJobGridDetailViewCollapse")
        .DetailExpand("BatchMonitor.onJobGridDetailViewExpand"))
    .ClientDetailTemplateId("grdBatchMonitorActionTemplate")
    .DataSource(ds => ds.WebApi().Read(r => r.Url(string.Format("{0}://{1}/api/v1/jobbatch/jobs/#=Id#",
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host)))
        .PageSize(10))
    .Selectable(s => s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
    .ToClientTemplate())
</script>
<script type = "text/kendo-tmpl" id = "grdBatchMonitorActionTemplate">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid < Demo.Tool.Web.Core.Entities.ActionItem > ()
    .Name("grdAction_#=Id#")
    .HtmlAttributes(new {
        @class = "batch-monitor-grid batch-monitor-grid-no-alt-row-color"
    })
    .Columns(c => {
        c.Bound(a => a.Description).Width("200");
        c.Bound(a => a.PercentageComplete).ClientTemplate("<div class='not-progress'><div class='action-not-progress'></div><span>0%</span></div><div class='progress action-progress'></div>").Width("100")
            .Width("200")
            .HtmlAttributes(new {
                style = "text-align: center;"
            });
        c.Bound(a => a.Id).Width("200").ClientTemplate("<span></span>");
        c.Bound(a => a.Status).Width("200").ClientTemplate("\\#= BatchMonitor.getStatusTemplate(Status) \\#");
        c.Bound(a => a.ParentId).Width("200").ClientTemplate("<span/>");
    })
    .Events(e => e.DataBound("BatchMonitor.onActionGridDatabound")
        .Change("BatchMonitor.onJobGridChange"))
    .DataSource(ds => ds.WebApi()
        .Read(r => r.Url(string.Format("{0}://{1}/api/v1/jobbatch/actions/#=Id#",
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host))).PageSize(10))
    .ToClientTemplate()) 
</script>
```

This is what the code above produces:

[image]

Now, oddly enough, if I manually size one of the column headers and then resize it seems to work just fine?

[image]

Am I missing a setting somewhere in order to correct this behavior?